# Llamar resultado de un funcion desde otra función cuando la funcion que me produce mi resultado utiliza otra funcion. Python

Tags: python

Tengo que generar una matriz en Python basándome en los datos de un archivo.
Los primeros dos datos de dicha matriz son la cantidad de filas y columnas de la matriz y el resto de elementos de la matriz van de 3 en 3 separados por comas.
Logré hacer esto pero para continuar con el proyecto tengo que modificar dicha matriz que me genera la función que hace todo eso (eliminarle datos en forma de cruz por ejemplo).
¿Cómo obtengo una variable que contenga la matriz que me genera esa función o algo por el estilo para poder trabajarla en otras funciones? (la función `almacenMatr` es a cuyo resultado me refiero)
Un ejemplo del contenido del archivo datpoblacion es el siguiente: 10 10 12sec 345 567 34sec 345 825.... y así sucesivamente hasta tener suficiente información para llenar una matriz 10x10.

```py
import numpy as np
# declaracion de la matriz global para trabajarla mas adelante.
matrizG = np.array([])

# Función que lee los datos del archivo, los almacena en una matriz y los muestra.
# la siguiente funcion corresponde al paso 1 y 2 de la asignación.
def almacenMatr():
    arch = open("D:Datpoblacion.txt", "r")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    # devuelve la siguiente linea del archivo como una cadena de caracteres, asi que int para transformarla en numero entero
    filas = int(arch.readline())
    columnas = int(arch.readline())
    # de esta manera no importa cuales sean los dos primeros datos del archivo, esos siempre seran las filas y columnas de la matriz (contando el codigo de mas adelante claro)
    datos_restantes = []
    datFinal = []  # creo 2 listas vacias
    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            datos_restantes.append(f"{arch.readline().strip()}{','}{arch.readline().strip()}{','}{arch.readline(
            ).strip()}")  # strip solo se asegura de que no haya/n despues de cada elemento en la matriz
        # aqui arriba a la lista vacia "datos_restantes" la uno con append a los datos restantes del archivo en el formato que quiero(concatenado de 3 en 3 separado por comas)
        # ahora uno la lista vacia "datFinal" a la lista que tiene los datos restantes del archivo que llene arriba en el formato que quiero
        datFinal.append(datos_restantes)
        datos_restantes = []  # vuelvo a vaciar la lista datos_restantes porque si no lo hago los datos de la matriz se repiten en una misma fila y ya??????

        # append= agrega elementos al final de las listas, lo utilizo mas que todo para añadirle cosas a listas vacias
    # L de local, convierte la lista "datFinal" en una matriz.
    matrizL = np.array(datFinal)
    # llamo la funcion con los 3 argumentos,el de cantidad filas, columnas y el de la matriz que acabamos de crear
    mostrar(filas, columnas, matrizL)
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    arch.close()

# funcion: le doy los 3 parametros de la funcion almacenMatr y los utiliza para imprimir los elementos de una matriz en una estructura de una tabla.
def mostrar(filas, columnas: int, matrizL: np.array):
    for f in range(0, filas, 1):  # itera sobre el numero de filas de la matriz (para que lea todas las filas, cada iteracion del bucle corresponde a una fila e igual abajo pero con columnas )
        for c in range(0, columnas, 1):  # itera sobre el numero de columnas de la matriz
            # dentro del bucle for "llama" la matriz para acceder a los elementos en la fila f y la columna c ,end imprime un espacio en  blanco al final de cada elemento de la matriz
            print(matrizL[f, c], end="  ")
        print()  # imprime una linea en blanco para separar los elementos de la matriz de la siguiente fila

# Con estas dos funciones de arriba cuando quiera trabajar la matriz simplemente agarro mi variable global llamada "matrizG" y la igualo a la llamada de la funcion AlmacenMatr.

# funcion que permite simular un bombardeo


def prin():
    print(matrizG)


def main():
    Salida = True
    while Salida:

        print("------------------------------------------------")
        print("¿Qué desea hacer?")
        print("------------------------------------------------")
        print("1. Mostrar los datos de una poblacion particular en una matriz")
        print("2. Simular un bombardeo a la matriz/poblacion particular")
        print("3. ")
        print("4. ")
        print("5. Salir")

        opcion = input("Ingrese su opción: ")

        if opcion == "1":
            almacenMatr()
        elif opcion == "2":
            print("1. Misil Balistico")
            print("2. Misil Crucero")
            print("3. Misil Antitanque")
            opcionsim = input("Eliga su tipo de misil: ")
            if opcionsim == "1":
                balistico()
        elif opcion == "3":
            prin()
        elif opcion == "4":
            credito()
        elif opcion == "5":
            Salida = False
        else:
            print("Opción inválida. Intente con un numero que se encuentre entre las opciones")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien, yo te recomiendo 3 maneras de encarar esto:

En python los elementos mutables como en este caso tu array se pasan por referencia, es decir, si pasas
el arreglo como argumento a una función que lo modifique, va a modificar directamente al valor original fuera
de la función, **pero** siempre y cuando tengas en cuenta de que lo que estas usando adentro de esa funcion tenga modificación "in-place",
(ej los métodos de tu arreglo de numPy: sort, append, etc, etc, salvo copy ese por razones obvias no
tiene modificación in-place), in-place se refiere a que podes realizar modificaciones (en este caso a tu arreglo)
sin la necesidad de hacer una copia. Tene en cuenta que si usas funciónes o lo que sea que no tenga modificaciones in-place tenes que asignar el retorno de esa función a la o las variables de tu interes. (menciono como se hace más abajo)

Otra que podes tener en cuenta es hacer que todas las funciónes en la que modifiques
a tu arreglo tengan un `return arr` al final, teniendo en cuenta que cada vez que uses esa función tenes que asignarle el retorno de esta funcion al arreglo de tu interes `arr = funcion_que_modifica_mi_array(arr)`, esto hace que tu codigo y el flujo de datos del programa sea mucho más entendible y explicito, y eso está buenisimo para que se
haga más facil de entender más adelante tanto a vs como a las personas que lo necesiten.

Y la última es que directamente juegues con [variables globales](https://thedataschools.com/python/variables/variables-globales/#:%7E:text=Para%20declarar%20una%20variable%20como,desde%20cualquier%20parte%20del%20programa), siempre teniendo en cuenta lo que mencione de las modificaciones in-place.

Ojala que esto te ayude, cualquier cosa avisa por acá abajo, sobre todo si lo que dije no gustó o hay una mejor forma de hacerlo,
todos estamos acá para aprender, saludos :D